# Android - Customise the order of ACRA report content?

Tags: android, acra

Having read [this documentation](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#choosing-which-fields-to-be-included-in-reports), I'm using this code...

```
import org.acra.ACRA;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;
import org.acra.ReportField;

@ReportsCrashes (
        formUri = "http://example.com/crash-reports/emailer.php",
        customReportContent = {ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT},
        sharedPreferencesName = "ACRA_SHARED_PREFS",
        sharedPreferencesMode = Context.MODE_PRIVATE
)
```

...to specify what content to include in my ACRA reports.

I would like to know if/how it's possible to also specify the *order* of this content, as the content in the emails that are sent from my `emailer.php` script seems to be a bit random.

Comment: Um, shouldn't it be the responsibility of `emailer.php` to handle the formatting of the emails? ACRA is just supplying the raw data.

Comment: It's the order of the content which ACRA sends the data from the app to `emailer.php` that is the issue. ACRA evidently provides a control for *what* content is sent, so my question is whether that control extends to determine *what order" the content is sent.

Comment: It is also preferable to do it at the Android side as that would mean I would only need to maintain one set of code.

Answer (score 0):

The `ReportBuilder` class in ACRA constructs the report. It does so in a deterministic fashion and the order is determine by the code in that class.